# Countdown to 3 month period android

Tags: android

In my application, i want to set a countdown timer from now to 17th of may. when the timer becomes 0 then a condition is applied. can one use calender or date

Comment: And your question is .....?

Comment: You could use something like http://android.appstorm.net/how-to/remote/how-to-push-notifications-to-your-android-with-pushover/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. If you want to invoke some code on May, 17th, you could use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

So, first you have to create Activity or Service (let's assume latter - ex. MyService) and then use code like that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(
    getApplicationContext(),
    1,
    intent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateMay17th, pi);
```

Also, you should avoid solution posted by user1566160 because it assumes your app will be running non-stop from now till May 17th, and one should never assume that.

Edit:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Calendar may17th = Calendar.getInstance();
    may17th.set(Calendar.MONTH, 4);
    may17th.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 17);
    may17th.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    may17th.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 17);

    if ( Calendar.getInstance().after(may17th) ) {
       setContentView(R.layout.new_layout);
    } else {
       setContentView(R.layout.old_layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: in fact i want some code to run on 17 may not before and it will displayed a default layout before 17th of may

Comment: It's still not very specific. As I understand: before May 17th when app is launched, it displays default layout. After May 17th, when app is launched, it displays different layout. Additionally, on May 17th app launches itself with new layout. Right?

Comment: nope, before 17 may it will display a default layout and from 17th onwards, it will displayed the desired layout

Comment: I've updated the answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: how to put a count down timer into it ?

Comment: You mean some text displayed to the user with the information how much time is left till May 17th?

Comment: It's a different question from your original one - maybe this tutorial will help you: http://www.androidaspect.com/2012/06/android-button-textview-example.html. In general, you probably want to use TextView.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both calendar as well as date :

```
Date d = new Date(2012, 02, 26); //Assign your desired date
Timer mytimer = new Timer();
mytimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
    //method to execute
     mymethod();
    }
}, d); 


    public void mymethod() {
        this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);

    }

    private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(Your condition) {
                //Execute your code
             }
       }
    };
```

Comment: how can i put a condition into it ?

Comment: what condition you want to put?

Comment: it won't display some piece of code before desired date. a default layout will be displayed instead

Comment: so you can use the layout inflater in //execute your code section and inflate the new layout.